# php: polymorphism on the iterator implementation of a array object?

Tags: php, iterator, polymorphism

I don't know if a array is really a object on php ... but, what I want is to change the array behavior on a foreach loop.

Something similar to this on java:

```
for( String it : myArr = new Array_Iterator( array) implements Iterator{
    public Array_Iterator( String[] arr){ this.arr = arr}
    /* interface implementation */
}){
    /* loop */
}
```

What I really want to accomplish is a kind of filter, so that I don't get entries from the array that I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the Array into an [ArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) and you're free to overwrite the regular methods. The [Spl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) provides a number of other [Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) and [Interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php) you might find useful. To filter arrays through iterators, use could use the [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).

Example from PHP Manual:

```
<?php
// This iterator filters all values with less than 10 characters
class LengthFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        // Only accept strings with a length of 10 and greater
        return strlen(parent::current()) > 10;
    }
}

$arrayIterator = new ArrayIterator(array('test1', 'more than 10 characters'));
$lengthFilter = new LengthFilterIterator($arrayIterator);

foreach ($lengthFilter as $value) {
    echo $value . "\n"; // ignores "test1" in array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the PHP function [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

> Iterates over each value in the input 
>   array passing them to the callback 
>   function. If the  callback  function
>   returns true, the current value from
>   input  is returned into the result
>   array. Array keys are preserved.

If you like the iterator based approach you could also take a look at the [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php), in particular [ArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) in conjunction with [FilterIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php).

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a kind of filter for elements of an array, try [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Make a function that returns true if the element is to be kept or false if it is not to be kept, then pass it to `array_filter`.